# Zcash proposal to use checkpoints to verify monetary supply

Tags: security, privacy, money-supply, zcash

Based on concerns about the trusted setup not being able to conclusively disprove the ability to create hidden inflation, [Zooko recently described](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6RLjcGVUnw&feature=youtu.be&t=29m00s) an idea to institute checkpoints to verify the total  monetary supply at fixed moments in time. What are the limitations, security and privacy implications of implementing such a measure?